# Limiting pm2 env to display environment

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've a node.js application running with some environment variables such as secret_keys, database name etc. All variables are set using export command before starting the server.
I'm using 'pm2' tool to start the server. When I use command 'pm2 env ', it displays all the environment correctly but my question is how to prevent display/showing of few variables such as secret keys, etc.

Comment: did you have any configuration for pm2 or pass environment as command line

Comment: No configuration but just following few variables,  export USER_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxx"; pm2 start server.js

Comment: You can manage this using custom configuration of pm2. Read more about from https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/ecosystem-file/?utm_source=pm2&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=rebranding

Comment: Setting environment is okay. In reality once you start your application using pm2, then anytime you login to the production machine where application is deployed and execute 'pm2 env 1' command it shows all the environment variables even if it's a new login session. This is what I want to avoid. I'm think of updating pm2 code to achieve just that unless there is already a way.

Comment: Well @Atarang any luck?